# Datatables excel cell format not becoming a list - Laravel

Tags: laravel, datatables

so i have datatables and I have excel export function which is working fine but when i have ul li tag under tr td tags, it becomes messy when i export in one cells.

here's my datatables also my table:

```
<div class="card-body">
                        <table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-bordered dt-responsive  nowrap w-100">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Buyer Name</th>
                                <th>Buyer Address</th>
                                <th>Invoice Number</th>
                                <th>Product </th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @forelse($campaign->orders as $order)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{ $order->id ?? '-'}}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $order->buyer_name ?? '-' }}</td>
                                        @foreach ($order->buyerOrderAddress as $address)
                                        <td>{{ $address->address }},  {{ $address->city->name }}, {{ $address->province->name }}, {{ $address->district->name }}, {{ $address->postalCode->postal_code }}</td>
                                        @endforeach
                                        <td>{{ $order->invoice_number ?? '-' }}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            @foreach($order->items as $item)
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>Name: {{ $item->product->name }}</li>
                                                    <li>Qty: {{ $item->qty }}</li>
                                                    <li>SKU: {{ $item->product->sku }}</li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </br>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                @empty

                                @endforelse
                            </tbody>

                    </div>
```

datatables export function:

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/libs/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/libs/datatables.net-responsive-bs4/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            let title = "{{ $campaign->title }}"
            $("#datatable-buttons").DataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'excelHtml5',
                        text : 'Export Excel',
                        filename: function() {
                            var d = new Date();
                            var n = d.getTime();
                            return 'list_buyer_delivery_' + n;
                        },
                    }
                ]
            }).buttons().container().appendTo("#datatable-buttons_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)"),$(".dataTables_length select").addClass("form-select form-select-sm")
        });
    </script>
```

and this how it displayed inside excel
[image: example of export data product]

how it should be:
[image: correct product list in my CMS]

so do i have an options or how to do it properly for that multiple data to displayed correctly?